# Finding joint distribution of order statistics

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, order-statistics

> Let $(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ be a random sample from an absolutely continuous distribution. Compute the limiting distribution of the order statistics $Y_1$ and $Y_n$.

I have seen similar problems but I didn't find it to be very helpful. How will I find the density function of the order statistics if the problem does not state what distribution $X$ has?

Comment: Well, the says limiting distribution right? So I'm assuming the limit is with respect to $n$. Then the min is probably negative infinity and similarly the max is infinity?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/102691/44719) can help you.